# Como instalar uma APK remotamente? (como a GooglePlay atualiza os apps)

Tags: android

Fiz uma service para baixar uma versão atualizada do meu aplicativo quando existir. Eu gostaria de exibir uma mensagem na tela avisando que há uma atualização e instalar/atualizar por trás meu aplicativo. Isso é possível? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Cara, faz tempo que eu não foco em Android, mas o googlePlay manda um push pro usuário quando existe uma nova versão.

Answer (score 2):

Instalar o aplicativo automaticamente em background eu creio que não é possível, pois o aparelho precisaria estar rooteado. Mas você pode mostrar uma tela perguntando se a pessoa quer baixar a atualização e deixá-la decidir se quer instalar ou não, segue o código comentado:

Estou considerando que você já está trazendo uma informação do service dizendo que tem uma atualização, então se tiver basta usar o codigo a seguir. No meu caso eu usei um `DialogFragment` para mostrar a tela dizendo que há uma atualização, mas isso fica a seu critério:

```
private static String file_url = "";
private String appName = "";
private File file;
private Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  button = (Button) ...;

  file_url = "url do seu arquivo .apk";
  appName = "nome do seu aplicativo (não esqueça de colocar .apk no final)";

  file = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + appName));

  if (file.exists()) { // Se o arquivo já existe (estou verifcando na pasta download)
     abreArquivo();
  }

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) }
           new DownloadAtualizacao().execute(file_url);
        }
    });

}

// Essa classe irá fazer o download do apk em background
class DownloadAtualizacao extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Faça algo como mostrar uma ProgressBar antes de começar a baixar
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        String erro = "N";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            int tamFile = conection.getContentLength();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 10 * 1024);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + appName));
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / tamFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { erro = "S"; }
        return erro;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // utilize para incrementar o progresso da ProgressBar
        // use assim progressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0])); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String erro) {
        if (erro.equals("S")) { 
           // Faça algo aqui se ocorreu algum erro
        }
        else {
           abreArquivo();
        }
    }
}

private void abreArquivo() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + appName);
    String type = getType(file);
    Intent it = new Intent();
    it.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    it.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
    try { startActivity(it); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}

// Pega o mymeType do arquivo(pode ser usado para qualquer tipo de arquivo)
private String getType(File file) {
    String type = null;
    try {
        URL u = file.toURL();
        URLConnection uc = null;
        uc = u.openConnection();
        type = uc.getContentType();
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return type;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

**Serviço**:

Seu Serviço pode informar ao app que existem novas atualizações!
Através de um `JSON` (por exemplo) você pode informar qual a versão mais atual.

Também é possível impedir um usuário utilizar uma versão muito antiga: 
Exemplo de JSON:

```
{“LAST_VERSION”: “3.7", 
“ALLOWED_WITH_UPDATE” :” 3.6", 
“NOT_ALLOWED”: “2.8”}
```

Sendo:

> **LAST_VERSION**: a última versão;
>
> **ALLOWED_WITH_UPDATE**: Existem atualizações, mas o usuário não necessita atualizar;
>
> **NOT_ALLOWED**: O Usuário necessariamente necessita atualizar;

**Android**:

Toda vez em que o app iniciar, ele realiza esta consulta e informa ao Usuário se existem alguma atualização (através de `Dialog`, por exemplo).

Se a versão é menor ou igual a **NOT_ALLOWED**, a `Dialog` permite apenas a atualização (travando as funcionalidades do app).

Para saber qual a versão do app utilize a seguinte Constante: `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`

Comment: Eu uso essa lógica, toda vez que dou login no meu aplicativo, ele já traz a versão do aplicativo do banco, e se ela for maior que a versão atual mostra um DialogFragment com o código que mostrei acima.

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa fazer nada específico para isso, a notificação de atualização é de responsabilidade do Google Play.

Você precisa apenas subir seu novo apk e mudar a `versionCode` dele no manifest.

**Edit**

Existe outras possibilidades como usar um **hockeyApp** ou **Fabric** que eles possuem um sistema que assim que o usuário abre o app ele abre um dialog informando que existe uma atualização disponível.

Comment: eu não vou colocar meu aplicativo no google play.

Comment: Você pode usar o hockeyApp mesmo assim. @daniel12345smith

Comment: @daniel12345smith Entenda minha crítica como construtiva e de forma nenhuma em ser chato, mas não concordo com sua abordagem. Não colocar na Google Play ter que controlar isso, além de "abrir o telefone" para fontes desconhecidas não é uma boa abordagem. Tenho aplicativos publicados nas contas de meus clientes, perfeitamente seguros e não tenho medo de deixar na play. Alguns inclusive a descrição é: aplicativo privado da empresa XPTO. Instalação automatizada sem ser distribuído pela Play acho que jamais será possível. Isso deixaria o Android extremamente MUITO vulnerável.